# iOS:Drawing MKTileOveraly on map causes High CPU usage and Memory.i can't find the reason for this.?

Tags: ios, mapkit, cpu-usage, mktileoverlay

i'm trying to add MKTileOverlay on map. when i start loading tile by fetching it from server, CPU usage suddenly increases. again on doing some action like zoom in zoom out or scrolling map cpu usage increases upto 200% whats the reason.?

Answer (score 0):

You might be allocating some objects continuously.
You can use instrument to check allocations in your app.